# Оптимизация кода map, reduce, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Ниже приведен рабочий код, который требуется оптимизировать с точки зрения производительности.

Описание задачи:
В списке сгенерированных сочетаний (df), требуется найти такие комбинации для которых выполянется условия:

1) Для каждой комбинация из listNumbers - должно совпадать от 2 до 3 элементов в строке в df.

2) Для каждой строки из df должно выполниться условие 1) хотя бы для одной комбинации из listNumbers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as iter
import math as mt
import timeit
from functools import reduce


listNumbers = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,5,6,7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(iter.combinations(range(1, 8), 5))
print(df)

containsMap = list(map(lambda x: df.isin(x).sum(1).between(2,3), listNumbers)) 

containsReduce = reduce(lambda f, x: f | x, containsMap)

print(df[containsReduce])
```

Исходный сгенерированный список

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0   1  2  3  4  5
1   1  2  3  4  6
2   1  2  3  4  7
3   1  2  3  5  6
4   1  2  3  5  7
5   1  2  3  6  7
6   1  2  4  5  6
7   1  2  4  5  7
8   1  2  4  6  7
9   1  2  5  6  7
10  1  3  4  5  6
11  1  3  4  5  7
12  1  3  4  6  7
13  1  3  5  6  7
14  1  4  5  6  7
15  2  3  4  5  6
16  2  3  4  5  7
17  2  3  4  6  7
18  2  3  5  6  7
19  2  4  5  6  7
20  3  4  5  6  7
```

Конечный отфильтрованный список

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0   1  2  3  4  5
1   1  2  3  4  6
2   1  2  3  4  7
5   1  2  3  6  7
6   1  2  4  5  6
7   1  2  4  5  7
8   1  2  4  6  7
9   1  2  5  6  7
10  1  3  4  5  6
11  1  3  4  5  7
12  1  3  4  6  7
13  1  3  5  6  7
14  1  4  5  6  7
17  2  3  4  6  7
18  2  3  5  6  7
19  2  4  5  6  7
20  3  4  5  6  7
```

В реальной задаче кол-во комбинаций в df - range (1, 101), а кол-во записей в listNumbers порядка 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas вообще очень тормозит по жизни. И, учитывая, что у вас числа не повторяются в комбинациях, оптимально будет использовать set-ы для хранения и сравнения наборов чисел. С ними скорость на несколько порядков больше стала, по моим подсчётам.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as iter
import math as mt
import timeit
from functools import reduce

listNumbers = list(map(set,[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,5,6,7]]))

df = list(map(set, iter.combinations(range(1, 8), 5)))
print(df)

containsMap = (any((2 <= len(x & y) <= 3 for x in listNumbers)) for y in df)
print(list(iter.compress(df, containsMap)))
```

Для range(1,8) timeit показало уменьшение с 5.14 ms до 30.3 µs, т.е. более чем в 100 раз.

P.S. Попробовал для больших range - что-то там улучшения вообще нет, там уже сам combination начинает времени есть гораздо больше, чем остальные части кода. Возможно, где-то у меня тут ещё перевод в list лишний, но, похоже, тут особо ничего не исправить уже. Разве что многопоточность сделать.

Comment: в вашем варианте как сохранить id комбинации ? на уровне df, там все просто. мне нужен id для других операций (фильтраций) со множеством сгенерированных значений

Comment: и почему вы использовали for, а не map?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Да что-то у меня с лямбдой от двух аргументов с ходу не срослось, поэтому for, а не map, наверняка можно доработать. Если вам нужны индексы, а не сами комбинации, то их можно через enumerate(df) например там получить. В общем, я идею предложил, а вы смотрите, как лучше. Мне работать надо :)

Comment: полезная инфо на счет производительности циклов https://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/